# Java Mail Server

Tags: java, email

I want to be able to send/receive mail from my Java Server application. Is there a standard tool chain to use? [The main thing is that I am writing an enterprise web app in Java, and I need a way to (1) send emails that contain authorization codes and (2) receive complaints.]

Thanks!

EDIT: I apologize. This is entirely my fault. I was not clear in the spec.

When I say send/receive emails, I meant: I need my application to be able to run it's own mail *server*. I don't have an external imap/pop3 account I'm using. My application need to provide the mail server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/) project might be a good starting point. It is a full-featured SMTP server written in Java. I am certain it is possible to interface other Java applications with James and/or write James extensions.

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for it's java mail and it's compatible with EE [here's the link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sending and receiving EMails you can do with the help of Java EE standard JavaMail API.  If your application is spring enabled, you can use org.springframework.mail package which has some good abstraction utilities.  Apart from this you need to have MTA(Mail Trasport Agent) like James as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a good alternative is Java E-mail Server (JES) at http://javaemailserver.sourceforge.net/. It's a full blown server for sending and receiving mail. "JES is a multi-featured hybrid MTA/MDA server written in the java programming language."